# Documentation Help Missing Link № 1

Tags: bug, documentation, hyperlinks, help-center

I came across ["Anatomy of a topic"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-anatomy) documentation help page and I see that link № `1` is missing:

> Each topic also includes a `[discussion tab][1]` that represent the history of all activity and commentary on the topic.

[image: No Link]

Comment: Is this documented?

Comment: +1 for the red text written like it should actually say "RED RUM"